# How to get my dwarves to kill a (were-)dwarf

Tags: dwarf-fortress

A werebeast infected one of my dwarves before they killed it, and I want my remaining dwarves to kill the infected dwarf, who is causing more damage than the original werebeast did.

But it seems that my dwarves are just being interrupted by and then killed by, but otherwise ignoring the were-dwarf-beast.

How can I make them kill him (it)?

Note that I am not asking for how can *I* kill a dwarf. There are plenty of ways like water and magma. I want my dwarves to take the issue in their hands, with a military solution, or a sheriff, or whatever *they* can do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Command a squad of well-equipped military dwarves to move to the werebeast's location, he will attack them and be slain. To issue a move order, hit <kbd>s</kbd> to open the squad menu, choose a squad, hit <kbd>m</kbd> to choose the move order, move the cursor to the werebeast and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Just to confirm. Will they kill this way a Fortress member converted into werebeast?

Comment: If he keeps attacking everything as you said, yes.

Comment: With the move order (not the attack order), the military will stop attacking your weredwarf as soon as he changes back to a regular dwarf, preventing loyalty cascades.